# Load Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address usign Ajax

Tags: cart, ajax, totals

To add a discount amount to cart total, I am using function `collect()` and `fetch()`.

```
Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Module Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract{



        public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
        {
            parent::collect($address);

            $this->_setAmount(0);
            $this->_setBaseAmount(0);

            $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
            if (!count($items)) {
                return $this; //this makes only address type shipping to come through
            }



    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
        {
            $amt = $address->getDiscountAmount();
```

I am using ajax to load the cart total block and show discount amount. The issue is, it displays the discount amount text and function `fetch()` is used for display purposes. but the cart total deductions are not happening as function `collect()` is not being called in ajax.

Is it possible to perform same operations in my controller that is being performed in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` ?

If I reload the page, I can see the applied discount and proper deductions but not on ajax click.

Please Help.

Comment: put full code...

Comment: Full code refernece - http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller call:

```
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
$quote->collectTotals();
```

The collector that you have written is called every time you call collectTotals on quote with the totals collected flag set to false.

The collector should look like below:

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $quote = $address->getQuote();


    if ($address->getAddressType() == 'billing' && !$quote->isVirtual())               return $this;

    $address->setDiscountAmount($address->getDiscountAmount() - $customDiscount);

    return $this;
}
```

One word of caution through - Discounts are maintained at item level and not at address level. So you may want to change your approach and involve a salesrule somehow.

Comment: Is `$quote` equal to `$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();` ? Also how to set data on `$address`  ?

Comment: Yes, correct for getting the quote.

Will edit in answer for the address collector.

Comment: `$quote->collectTotals();` will call `function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)` but how `$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);` works and what if we set it to `true` ?

Comment: $quote->collectTotals() one the first line checks for the totals_collected_flat, if it is set to true it returns without doing anything. Look at the definition : Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals()